# Give algebraic and geometric descriptions of the $\operatorname{Span} \{ a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Give algebraic and geometric descriptions of $\operatorname{Span} \{ a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \}$ where

$a_1 = (1, -1, -2), a_2 = (3, -3, -1), a_3 = (2, -2, -4), a_4 = (2, -2, 1)$

So far, I have:
$$
\begin{matrix}
 \;\;\,1 & \;\;\,3 & \;\;\,2 & \;\;\,2 \\ 
-1 &-3 &-2 &-2\\
-2 & -1 &-4 & \;\;\,1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Though, I feel like I'm missing a column. What should this system be equal to?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 2\\ 
 -1&  -3&  -2& -2\\ 
 -2&  -2&  4& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

only use elementary row operation,we can get

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &2  &-1 \\ 
 0&1  & 0 &1 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

then,$a_1=2a_3$,and $a_4=-a_1+a_2$

$\operatorname{Span} \{ a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \}=\operatorname{Span} \{ a_1, a_2\}$

Comment: Great! So this would be a sufficient algebraic solution. The geometric solution would be the plane that contains vectors a1, a2, and 0; more specifically, the plane that contains the line in R3 through vectors a1 and 0 and the line in R3 through vectors a2 and 0. I was confused as to the easiest way to find the algebraic solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: what confused you?

Comment: I missed the obvious--I didn't realize adding and subtracting the results of Gaussian elimination would help me prove linear dependence.

Comment: if you think my answer is right,you can select it as the best answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To start, notice that $a_1=2a_3$, thus we may eliminate $a_3$ as redundant. Can you see a relation between the remaining vectors?

Comment: They each increment by 1 or -1, depending on the sign...

Comment: Remember, if we can write one vector as a linear combination of the other two, then that vector adds nothing to the span...there is a linear relationship between $a_1=(1,-1,-2), a_2=(3,-1,-1),$ and $ a_4=(2,-2,1)$. What is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I only see a relationship between a1 and a3. The others don't seem to have a simple constant to equal one another.

Comment: I know that if a1 = 2a3, then the two vectors are *not* linearly independent, correct?

Comment: That is correct. And if $a_1=ca_2+da_4$ for some constants $c,d$, then $a_1$ is dependent on $a_2$ and $a_4$. What are the constants in this case?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't understand the term linear combination fully. If ALL are linearly dependent... then geometrically this would just be a line in R2 space.

Comment: That would be the case if they were ALL constant multiples of each other, but that is not the case here. There are two linearly independent vectors; find them and they will determine a plane.

Comment: Ok. Is there a fast way to compute linear independence? For example, setting up a matrix and then realizing there is no solution when 0 = a number?

Comment: I calculated the matrix of a2, a4 = a1 and got

1 0 | 3, 
0 1 | -1,
0 0 | 0, but I'm not sure what this means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For the geometric description, observe that all four vectors are linear combinations of $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.  So the span is the plane that contains $(0,0,0)$ and those two points.  This plane includes the $Z$-axis, and makes $45^\circ$ angles with the $X$- and $Y$-axes.